# php multiple preg replace on a single string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string lets say this :

```
$string="Hi! [num:0] with [num:1]";
```

and an array like this :

```
$array[0]=array('name'=>"na","id"=>22);
$array[1]=array('name'=>"nam","id"=>19);
```

Now when i try to replace this string with using `preg_replace()` like this:

```
$string=preg_replace('#\!\s+\[num:(\d+)\]#ie','.$array[\1]["name"]',$string);
```

What i am trying to do this in the replace is that search for the pattern [num:x] and then replace it by the name in corresponding array of the key 'x'

It works perfect for the first match but doesn't works for the second one at all. That means after this the output i get is :

```
$string="Hi! na with [num:1]";
```

While what i want should be :

```
$string="Hi! na with nam";
```

What change should i make in this ?

Comment: Have you tried appending a `g` to the `#ie` part

Comment: Ok. when i made #ieg i get an error `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in /root/pBot/te/test.php on line 18
`

Comment: Sorry, mixing this with javascript regex engine :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you mentioned will only match the first, as it check the exclamation symbol.

Remove the '!' so that it will replace all.

```
#\s+\[num:(\d+)\]#ie
```

Note : But it won't remove the '!' from the string. Also checking \s+ is not a good idea, because the regex will break if a placeholder in the string doesn't contain a space before.

```
#\[num:(\d+)\]#ie
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont have much knowledge of regex i just used what i got from another answer here :D

Comment: when i try to use regex like this : `preg_replace('#\[num:(\d+)\]#ie','isset($array[\1]) ? "! ".$array[\1]["name"] : " "',$string);` my output is has an extra '!'. Why ? and how to fix.

Comment: Hope your output is "Hi! ! na with ! nam". The first exclamation symbol is which is already in the string, and the second and third are  the ones which you inserted using isset($array[\1]) ? expression.

Comment: Just use $string=preg_replace('#\[num:(\d+)\]#ie','$array[\1]["name"]',$string); It will give your desired output

Comment: @Jithun I use that isset because I want to check if the entered num is a valid key in the array or not. And it was not there before removing the `\!`

Comment: If you only need to check whether the key exists, why do append an exclamation in the replace(#2nd comment). To check whether the key exists, put $string=preg_replace('#\[num:(\d+)\]#ie','isset($array[\1]) ? $array[\1]["name"] : " "',$string);